# How to Pair Samsung Watch6 Class to Android Studio on Windows - Fails 2 Ways

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I am trying to pair a Samsung Watch6 Classic with the latest Android Studio on a Windows box.

I've found two ways that don't work - searching for a way that does.

**First way that does not work**

- In Device Manager, click the "Pair Devices Using Wi-Fi" icon
- Click "Pair using pairing code"
- Tap "Pair new device" on watch
- Device Manager sees it
- Click "Pair"
- Asks for 6 digit code I enter the code and click
  "Pair"
- Sits and spins for two minutes
- Shows [!] There was an error pairing the device.

If there are more detailed logs of why - I don't know where to find them.

**Second way that does not work**

- Install adb platform-tools
- Go to watch, tap on "Pair new device"
- Issue the following commands in a CMD with admin privs
- `netsh interface portproxy reset`
- `adb kill-server`
- `adb start-server`
- `adb pair 192.168.68.112:40297`  <-- this info is now displayed on watch

It successfully pairs!

But... android studio never becomes aware of it.
I have tried closing and restarting studio, but now effect.